# save the username, role and name in session variable on authenticated login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've a created a login page using you tube tutorial. It showed me creating the login procedure via some packages. I have forgot what it was.

Now what I want to do is save the username, role and name in session variable if the user is valid user. How can I do this? It is the code created from that package installation.

controller code LoginController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/book';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

code for AuthenticatesUsers.php

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

trait AuthenticatesUsers
{
    use RedirectsUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Show the application's login form.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    /**
     * Handle a login request to the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);

        // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
        // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
        // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }

        // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
        // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
        // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }

    /**
     * Validate the user login request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return void
     */
    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            $this->username() => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to log the user into the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->guard()->attempt(
            $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
    }

    /**
     * Send the response after the user was authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
                ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    /**
     * The user has been authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  mixed  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the failed login response instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the login username to be used by the controller.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function username()
    {
        return 'email';
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out of the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        return redirect('/');
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during authentication.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard();
    }
}
```

Comment: Laravel provides auth scaffolding and access to the authenticated user model via `Auth::user()`.  I suggest you read through the docs.

Comment: @Devon Please can you elaborate your reply. I am new to laravel. How can I use this `Auth::user()`? Where is this `Auth::user()`? Please help!!!

Comment: I suggest reading the docs at laravel.com/docs.  You really should read through most of it before even starting with Laravel.  Otherwise, you're bound to be using things the wrong way or making life harder for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

With Laravel 5, once you have authenticated the user you can also call the login user from the Auth class like below

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

Now, with the user object you can get the users name and role, so there is no need for manually saving it in the session. Once the user is logged in, you can call the above method.

Also, I think this will work with the package above as the LoginController uses the AuthenticatedUsers trait.

So, anywhere you need the user info just called \Auth::user();

I would recommend this as it is a best practice in Laravel, hope it help.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Please can you explain me where should I use it `Auth::user()`, I mean in `LoginController.php` or `AuthenticatesUsers.php` and at inside which code block in the file ? Pleas help!!

Comment: You can use it in any controller or blade that you need the user information

Comment: This is the full documentation about it https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication

Here is the full namespace for the class use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; to use in any controller and you can use \Auth in the blade to use it.

Answer (score 1):

from your code, after the user is validated, it is routed to the book.

```
protected $redirectTo = '/book';
```

so to check, keep this code block in any of the initial methods in `book controller` and see the result.

```
return response()->json(Auth::user());
```

You will get all the `attributes` of `authenticated user`. I think you can proceed further now.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this link for storing data into your session.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session#storing-data

Comment: I am new to laravel. Where should I keep the code block for storing values in session? i mean it should be in `LoginController.php` or `AuthenticatesUsers.php` at what code block ? Please elaborate it. Thank You!!!

Comment: If you are storing users detail then please keep in `LoginController.php`. 
Because it is very important information and you can not call user information from any class.